# Crear arreglo bidimensional de char de forma dinámica teniendo la forma estática

Tags: c++

Cómo puedo crear la matriz de *registro* como un puntero para que sea dinámico?
Aquí estoy asignando las cadenas char estáticamente pero no sé cómo hacerlo dinámico para dos dimensiones.

```
const int categoria = 5;
const int largo_palabras = 50;

int main()
{
    char registro[categoria][largo_palabras];

    for (int i = 0; i < categoria; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese la categoría: [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        cin >> registro[i];
    }

    cout << "El registro completo es: " << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < categoria; x++){
        cout << registro[x] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

char **asigMemoria(const int FILA, const int COLUMNA);
void liberar(char **&ptr, const int FILA);

int main()
{
    const int categoria      = 5;
    const int largo_palabras = 50;
   
    // crear matriz de 5x50
    char **registro = asigMemoria(categoria,largo_palabras);

    for (int i = 0; i < categoria; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese la categoría: [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        cin >> registro[i];
    }

    cout << "El registro completo es: " << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < categoria; x++)
    {
        cout << registro[x] << endl;
    }

    // liberar memoria y volver a null el puntero de la matriz
    liberar(registro,categoria);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

char **asigMemoria(const int FILA, const int COLUMNA)
{
    char **ptr = new char*[FILA];

    for(int i{}; i < FILA; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = new char[COLUMNA];
    }

    return ptr;
}

void liberar(char **&ptr, const int FILA)
{
    if(ptr != nullptr)
    {
        for(int i{}; i < FILA; i++)
        {
            delete [] ptr[i];
        }

        delete [] ptr;
        ptr = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por qué utilizaste `int i{}` en los ciclos `for` ?

Comment: Es una caracteristica propia de C++ se llama inicializacion uniforme y es similar a hacer esto `int i = 0;` y no solo sirve para inicializar enteros, tambien se puede inicializar punteros a null, strinng vacios, o fin de cadena `\0` para los tipo char, etc. tambien lo puedes usar para inicializar objetos lo cual llamara al constructor vacio, la gracia de esto es que el valor a inicializar lo deduce segun el tipo de la variable

Comment: Gracias! Otra pregunta ¿por qué llamas a la variable `**&ptr` con doble asterisco y con ampersand? ¿Es para decir que llamarás a un doble puntero por referencia ya que la función `liberar` no retorna valor?

Comment: La expresión `char *ptr;` se lee puntero a char, `char **ptr;` puntero de puntero a char, si tuviera más asteriscos sería puntero de puntero de puntero... y así. Los niveles de punteros no tienen límite, pero se hace increíblemente difícil de entender así que lo común es usar hasta dos y el uso del ampersand es precisamente para hacer el paso por referencia, lo que significa que todo lo que se haga sobre esa variable se verá reflejada en la variable de la llamada, de no ser así no tendria efecto asignar el nulo `ptr = nullptr;` después de liberar la memoria.

Comment: y la respuesta a tu pregunta `¿Es para decir que llamarás a un doble puntero por referencia ya que la función liberar no retorna valor?` Si